# "came" meaning in context

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs, synonyms

I saw a word of which I could not find any meaning matched with the context in several dictionaries.

> After a long journey of sailing, the ship was wrecked by angry wind. A man who was on board escaped from the ship before destroyed. He swam to the shore, and he stayed in an island.
> After days **came**, he found a ship sailing.

I think that the verb **came** means passed. I couldn't find the exact meaning in the dictionary though.

What is the exact meaning of the word, and what synonyms are there?

Comment: This is an unnatural usage of "came" by a non-native speaker, so I'm closing this question to new answers. "Passed" would be much more natural.

Comment: Can you provide the source of this quote?

Comment: @James K https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4IDMTAkvEM&t=1027s  It is one of YouTube trailers, I don’t remember the point showing that word “came” though.

Comment: @JamesK I just showed a shorten story which includes the phrase "After days came." of the trailer content.

Comment: To make your question answerable you should use the exact quote from your source.  If you shorten it you might change something important I've searched through your source and the phrase "After days came" does not appear.  The closest I can find is "When day came".  This has a quite different meaning.  You need to get your quote right or the question is impossible to answer.

Comment: Spring comes came late this year(=to happen)

Answer (score 1):

"after days came" is a way to describe how the days "passed" (synonym in this case). Think of it like this:

> After a few days passed by, he found a ship sailing